# Could not transfer artifact Transfer failed

Tags: java, maven

I am getting below error for maven projects in intellij.
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:3.3 from/to other-mirror (http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Transfer failed for http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom ProxyInfo{host='123.45.6.
This is my pom.xml
'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
'''
```

This is my settings.xml

```
'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
<mirrors>
 <mirror>
  <id>internal-repository</id>
  <name>Maven Repository Manager running on https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</name>
  <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
 </mirror>
</mirrors>
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url> <!-- the https you've been looking for -->
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled> <!-- or set to true if desired, default is false -->
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
   <proxies/>
</settings>
'''
```

I tried to add proxy but no use. tried to add mirror as well but not working. Please let me know if you faced and fixed the same issue

Comment: Based on the error message `ProxyInfo{host='123.45.6. ` you are using a proxy which is wrongly configured either in your settings.xml or the proxy itself...